# My React App gives error when connected to Nodejs API (MS SQL Server)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server

i was just building a react app to display movie contents. I got my node api using mssql working fine and tested with postman for all CRUD operations.

When i started creating the react app and use this api, it shows following errors. Could u please help.

My node api json format:

```
{
  Film_id: 1,
  film_name: 'Van Helsing',
  actor: 'Hugh Jackman',
  actress: 'Kate B',
  pub_date: '01/05/2008',
  director: 'Brad',
  producer: 'Universal',
  prod_cost: 6454988948,
  dist_cost: 2464546,
  category: 'Horror',
  cert_category: 'U/A',
  poster: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e1 00 60 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 02 00 31 01 02 00 07 00 00 00 26 00 ... 122428 more bytes>
},
```

The error i am getting:

```
    Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, data}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
anonymous function)
D:/react2/andrew/src/Films.js:16
  13 |        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'Films')
  14 |        .then(response=>response.json())
  15 |        .then(data=>{
> 16 |            this.setState({fls:data});
     | ^  17 |        });
  18 |    }
  19 |
```

My react component:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';


export class Films extends Component{

    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.state={fls:[]}
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'Films')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({fls:data});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    render(){
        const {fls}=this.state;
                return(
            <div>
                <Table className="mt-4" striped border hover size="sm">
                    <thread>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Film ID</th>
                        <th>Film Name</th>
                        <th>Actor</th>
                        <th>Actress</th>
                        <th>Published Date</th>
                        <th>Director</th>
                        <th>Producer</th>
                        <th>Production Cost</th>
                        <th>Distribution Cost</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Cert Category</th>
                        <th>Poster</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thread>
                    <tbody>
                        {fls.map(fl=>
                            <tr key={fl.Film_id}>
                                <td>{fl.Film_id}</td>
                                <td>{fl.film_name}</td>
                                <td>{fl.actor}</td>
                                <td>{fl.actress}</td>
                                <td>{fl.pub_date}</td>
                                <td>{fl.director}</td>
                                <td>{fl.producer}</td>
                                <td>{fl.prod_cost}</td>
                                <td>{fl.dist_cost}</td>
                                <td>{fl.category}</td>
                                <td>{fl.cert_category}</td>
                                <td>{fl.poster}</td>
                                <ts>Edit / Delete</ts>

                            </tr>)}
                    </tbody>

                </Table>
            </div>          
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(fls)` and check if it's an array

Comment: It looks like the `poster` property is a buffer object. You can't render that directly

Comment: @Jayce444 could u suggest a way to display the binary data inside poster to an image in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to map through the values of your object. If you want to render the values of your "fls" object you have to write Object.values(fls).map(fls => ...

you can check the docs here: [Objects.values MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Great. It works. But need some suggestions to display the image which is saved as varbinary(max) in database